# How to create a sidebar in Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, bho

I want to create a sidebar same as Firefox sidebar in IE, something similar to IE developer toolbar, IE http analyzer, ....
Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Creating Custom Explorer Bars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776819.aspx). This page contains the details and code samples.